# NLP: Replicating a sentiment function for pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, function, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am passing function to count the number of positive and negative words inside a dataframe.

I am using a  dictionary like this:

```
import re
 

lmdict = {'Negative': ['closes','buoyed','underpinned', 'volatile'],
          'Positive': ['up','strong','higher','versatile']}
```

and a negate dictionary to classify negation words:

```
negate = [ "havent", "isnt", "mightnt", "mustnt",
          "neither", "don't", "hadn't", "hasn't", "haven't", "isn't", "mightn't", "mustn't", "neednt", "needn't",
          "never", "none", "nope", "nor", "not", "nothing", "nowhere", "oughtnt", "shant", "shouldnt", "wasnt",
          "werent", "oughtn't", "shan't", "shouldn't", "wasn't", "weren't", "without", "wont", "wouldnt", "won't",
          "wouldn't"]
```

The function that I was using is useful for individual news articles  is the following:

```
def negated(word):
    """
    Determine if preceding word is a negation word
    """
    if word.lower() in negate:
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
 
def tone_count_with_negation_check(dict, article):
    """
    Count positive and negative words with negation check. Account for simple negation only for positive words.
    Simple negation is taken to be observations of one of negate words occurring within three words
    preceding a positive words.
    """
    pos_count = 0
    neg_count = 0
 
    pos_words = []
    neg_words = []
 
    input_words = re.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+n\'t|[a-zA-Z]+\'s|[a-zA-Z]+)\b', article.lower())
 
    word_count = len(input_words)
 
    for i in range(0, word_count):
        if input_words[i] in dict['Negative']:
            neg_count += 1
            neg_words.append(input_words[i])
        if input_words[i] in dict['Positive']:
            if i >= 3:
                if negated(input_words[i - 1]) or negated(input_words[i - 2]) or negated(input_words[i - 3]):
                    neg_count += 1
                    neg_words.append(input_words[i] + ' (with negation)')
                else:
                    pos_count += 1
                    pos_words.append(input_words[i])
            elif i == 2:
                if negated(input_words[i - 1]) or negated(input_words[i - 2]):
                    neg_count += 1
                    neg_words.append(input_words[i] + ' (with negation)')
                else:
                    pos_count += 1
                    pos_words.append(input_words[i])
            elif i == 1:
                if negated(input_words[i - 1]):
                    neg_count += 1
                    neg_words.append(input_words[i] + ' (with negation)')
                else:
                    pos_count += 1
                    pos_words.append(input_words[i])
            elif i == 0:
                pos_count += 1
                pos_words.append(input_words[i])
 
    print('The results with negation check:', end='\n\n')
    print('The # of positive words:', pos_count)
    print('The # of negative words:', neg_count)
    print('The list of found positive words:', pos_words)
    print('The list of found negative words:', neg_words)
    print('\n', end='')
 
    results = [word_count, pos_count, neg_count, pos_words, neg_words]
 
    return results
```

```
tone_count_with_negation_check(lmdict, article)
```

But I want to use for this function for dataframes like this:

```
articles = pd.DataFrame({'articles': ['S Africa s JSE closes firmer buoyed by industrial stocks',
              'Sasol says HEPS up percent current economic climate volatile'
              'Sasol Delivers Strong Financial Results Underpinned by Higher Crude Oil and Product Demand',
            'South Africa s Sasol H earnings up on higher oil']})
```

Can you help me to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest making `negate` a `set` rather than a `list`, because the test `word.lower() in negate` is fast if `negate` is a set, but slow if it is a list. Just use `{ ... }` instead of `[ ... ]` when defining `negate`.

Comment: insert the dictionaries and lists into the functions, so u won't have to pass variabls to the function beside the article, then use articles.apply(tone_count_with_negation_check)